# Is there a way to install my app through Android Studio without using the instant run feature?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-run

For whatever reason, when I install my app through Android Studio with the "run app" button, the MY_PACKAGE_RECEIVED intent filter doesn't seem to get triggered. This causes my app to fail to properly register some AlarmManager alarms, which I usually only notice the next day, when said alarms fail to fire.

Is there a way to tell Android Studio to install my app without using the "instant run" feature? I still want to use instant run most of the time, but the last install I make each day needs to be a full proper install.

So far the only solution I found was to manually create the APK with  `Build -> Build APK(s)` and then jump into a terminal to install it with `adb install`.

Comment: Just turn off Instant Run from Settings in Android Studio.

Comment: I still want to have instant run on while I'm working on the app though.  Do you know if there is a good way to install without instant run only when I need it? (Having to go inside the settings to turn it off and on is more work than hopping into a terminal to do an `adb install`)

Comment: In that case, you can try *Rebuild Project* and then install the app at day end.